# Bind a combobox - dealing with foreign keys

Tags: c#, combobox

In my database I have a table Cars which contains (among other things) an idCategory column which is a foreign key. That foreign key refers idCategory in the Category table which contains the description of the category.

Now in my C# application I got a form that is used to add new cars. There is a combobox to choose the category.

```
comboboxCat.DataSource = datatable1;
comboboxCat.DisplayMember = "categoryDescription";
comboboxCat.ValueMember = "idCategory";
```

So I set the DataSource of the ComboBox to the DataTable that contains the data of Category table, and I set the id as the valueMember and the Description as DisplayMember.

I also have a DataSet containing the table Cars.
What I want to do is to automatically update the Car data in the DataSet when the value of the Combobox is changed. I don't know how to bind it. In a datagridview it's easy because I just have to set the DataPropertyName of the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. But there's not such properties in a normal ComboBox. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to update Dataset from Combobox or vise versa? At form load you can display data on combobox, when combobox index changed you can update your data set, will that do for you?

Comment: I would like to bind the Combobox selected value with the Dataset so if I change the Combobox value it reflects the change in the DataSet and vice-versa

Comment: Then you could, call your connection strings, db open, bind dataset to ComboBox at FORM_LOAD. Next at ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event you may set INSERT string to table using values changed in Commobo box. [Check this out please](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winformsdatacontrols/thread/7d447ecc-5506-429b-907b-bbaf43313be6) Also read about some of the issues reported with 2-way data binding for combobox.

Answer (score 1):

I belive you have to bind the IdCategory field from the Cars DataTable to the SelectedValue of the ComboBox.

Comment: I just don't understand why you didn't accept my answer...You can also do the DataBinding on the designer as well, no need to listen to any event.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what I was looking for : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/04/25/tips-on-related-data-binding-and-comboboxes.aspx

My answer is to use DataBindings to make the link

Comment: Glad you find an article that you can refer to. And what we talk so far is all based on DataBinding :) At the end you can notice that this article itself using Form_Load() and SelectedIndexChanged() events ;) Good luck!